# value of $ac(a-c)+ad(a-d)+bc(b-c)+bd(b-d)$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a,b$ are the distinct roots of the equation $x^2+20x-2020=0$ and $c,d$ are the distinct complex roots of the equation $x^2-20x+2020=0$, then the value of
> $ac(a-c)+ad(a-d)+bc(b-c)+bd(b-d)$ is

Here $a+b=-20$, $ab=-2020$
and $c+d=20$, $cd=2020$

Now $=a^2c-ac^2+a^2d-ad^2+b^2c-bc^2+b^2d-b^2d$

$=a^2(c+d)-a(c^2+d^2)+b^2(c+d)-bc(b-c)$

$[(a+b)^2-2ab](c+d)+b^2(c+d)-bc(b-c)$

How can I find value of $bc$ and $(b-c)$?

Comment: Check your calculations once.

Comment: Note that the values of $a$ and $b$ are not distinguished from each other in their definition. For example, if they were the roots of $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$, then it could be that $a = 1, b = -2$ or $a = -2, b = 1$. Just saying that they are the roots of an equation does not say which is which root. And the same is true for $c$ and $d$. Thus there are in general four values that $bc$ can have and four values for $b-c$, depending on which roots you assign to $b$ and $c$. You have to express the value you want in a way that is symmetric between $a$ and $b$, and between $c$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks friends got it